# Save Keras model at specific epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras to do some training on my dataset and it is time consuming to keep running every time to locate the number of epochs needed to get the best results. I tried using callbacks to get the best model, but it just does not work and usually stops too early. Also, saving every N epochs is not an option for me.

What I am trying to do is save the model after some specific epochs are done. Let's say for example, after `epoch = 150` is over, it will be saved as `model.save(model_1.h5)` and after `epoch = 152`, it will be saved as `model.save(model_2.h5)` etc... for few specific epochs.

Is there a way to implement this in Keras ? I already searched for a method but no luck so far.

Thank you for any help/suggestion.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Edit**
In most cases it's enough to use name formatting suggested by @Toan Tran in his answer.

But if you need some sophisticated logic, you can use a [callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/), for example

```
import keras

class CustomSaver(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        if epoch == 2:  # or save after some epoch, each k-th epoch etc.
            self.model.save("model_{}.hd5".format(epoch))
```

`on_epoch_end` is called at the end of each epoch; `epoch` is a number of epoch, latter argument is a logs (you can read about other callback methods in docs). Put the logic into this method (in example it's as simple as possible).

Create saver object and put it into `fit` method:

```
import keras
import numpy as np

inp = keras.layers.Input(shape=(10,))
dense = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')(inp)
out = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense)
model = keras.models.Model(inp, out)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy",)

# Just a noise data for fast working example
X = np.random.normal(0, 1, (1000, 10))
y = np.random.randint(0, 2, 1000)

# create and use callback:
saver = CustomSaver()
model.fit(X, y, callbacks=[saver], epochs=5)
```

In the `bash`:

```
!ls
Out:
model_2.hd5
```

So, it works.

Comment: Thank you sir !! The solution seems to be working well.

Answer (score 16):

```
checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('model{epoch:08d}.h5', period=5) 
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

Did you try checkpoint? `period=5` means model is saved after 5 epoch

More details [here](https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint)

Hope this help :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I cannot afford to save every k epochs. My disk might run out of space before it even reaches the epochs I'm interested in

Comment: Excuse me .. if there are many models saved which one I should use it for evaluation and prediction ?

Comment: @user5520049 you can use the best model based on its val loss, the lower the better model.

Comment: i appreciate your reply thanks .. i got for the first 3 epochs as i set it to 20 this results .. 
`loss: 4.7179 - accuracy: 0.2422 - val_loss: 4.2133 - val_accuracy: 0.2912`
`loss: 4.1017 - accuracy: 0.3009 - val_loss: 3.9599 - val_accuracy: 0.3136 `
`loss: 3.9611 - accuracy: 0.3131 - val_loss: 3.8945 - val_accuracy: 0.3202` will it make a difference if i wait or how can i decide that model is enough for training

Comment: Well, It seems like your model is underfitting, the ```val_loss``` and ```val_accuracy``` present your model do not "learn" anything from the dataset, maybe you need to modify it to achieve better results or keep training to 100, 200 epochs. Anyway, when the ```val_loss``` is approximate 0 (~0.001), means it converge and you can stop training.

Comment: thanks a lot but excuse me how do you know that is under fitting problem ? i increased it to 70 epochs and hope it will work well .. but it will take days to finish .. is there any way to make it fast .. i can work on 2060 rtx with gpu

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't comment on posts yet. So, I'm adding on to `@Toan Tran`'s answer. With the latest version of Keras, the argument `period` is deprecated. Instead, we can use `save_freq`.

In the following example, the model is saved after every epoch.

```
checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(model_save_path+'/checkpoint_{epoch:02d}', save_freq='epoch')
H=model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train,epochs=epoch_no,verbose=2, callbacks=[checkpoint])
```

You can find more details from [keras documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint).